# Assign same variable to different pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I assign the variables year and month to different pandas dataframes.

```
            df_A['year'] = year
            df_A['month'] = month
            df_B['year'] = year
            df_B['month'] = month
            df_C['year'] = year
            df_C['month'] = month
            df_D['year'] = year
            df_D['month'] = month
```

Instead of the above assignments, is there a way to do it succinctly in Python.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: you can use `globals()` and find all the dataframe variables and then assign to them

Comment: Why do you have so many different DataFrames just floating around? Fix that, either by storing them in a dict, or if they are similar enough concatenating and using a MultiIndex to label, and you circumvent this unnecessary problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store dfs in a list, and for loop it?

```
for df in df_list:
    df['year'] = year
    df['month'] = month
```